# Maven shade-plugin not copying classes to .jar file

Tags: scala, maven, executable-jar, gatling, maven-shade-plugin

I have downloaded [Gatling Maven Example](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo) and trying add mvn shade plugin in it as below, the jar get created but it doesn't contains any classes, so it fails during execution

```
E:\projects\gatling-maven>java -jar target\gatling-maven-plugin-demo-2.2.3.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Engine
```

Here is pom.xml I have added

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
  <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin-demo</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gatling.version>${project.version}</gatling.version>
    <gatling-plugin.version>2.2.1</gatling-plugin.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>Engine</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and package structure is as

[image]

Comment: 1. I believe you should have put fully-qualified name for `Engine`. 2. Your `Engine` is now in `src/test/` which is of course not going to be packaged into the jar

Comment: Recap in my prev comment: Your Engine is now in **src/test/** which is of course not going to be packaged into the jar

Comment: is `target/` containing files as expected?

Comment: and, I will strongly suggest you to make a toy project, which contains only one main class, and try to use shade plugin to make a jar from it.  Make sure you know what you are doing

Comment: Yes jar, classes files are thr inside `target` folder but my.jar didn't contain my `package/classes`

Comment: Thanks @AdrianShum for all your help, finally problem solved, we have to compile the project to get classes into our jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move all your resources and scala files to `src\main\resources` and `src\main\scala`. Shade plugin will not include your test resources and scala files. I have also tried [shadedTestjar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#shadeTestJar) and it also does not work. The other option could be you use either

1. Maven Dependency plugin and move all dependency manually - Error prone and ugly
2. Use Assembly plugin - Not suitable

I have tried moving your resources and scala files in `src/main` and it has worked. Following is working pom content,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin-demo</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gatling.version>${project.version}</gatling.version>
        <gatling-plugin.version>2.2.1</gatling-plugin.version>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configFolder>src/main/resources</configFolder>
                            <dataFolder>src/main/resources/data</dataFolder>
                            <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                            <requestBodiesFolder>src/main/resources/request-bodies</requestBodiesFolder>
                            <simulationsFolder>src/main/scala</simulationsFolder>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Engine</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

---

Try after changing your following plugin configuration,

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>Engine</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

There are still file not found exception but I believe they are trivial to solve.

Comment: Hey Gaurav, I have made changes suggested by you and now I can see so many things inside jar but still my issue persists when I ran the jar.
`java -jar gatling-maven-plugin-demo-2.2.3.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Engine` could you please help

Comment: Now, I have moved the `Engine.scala` into `compuerdatabase` package and provided full qualified name but issue still exists `Error: Could not find or load main class computerdatabase.Engine`

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, it's indeed a great help. It's finally it's picked up the classes _/\_

Answer (score 1):

First learn about the Maven standard directory structure convention.  Your main project source is now put under `src/test/` instead of the correct `src/main/`, so they are treated as to be used in unit test.  Therefore it will not be packaged.